# How to call recording Callback in custom CFRunLoop in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio, cfrunloop

I am recording audio in iPhone ..

This is my Audio Queue object

> ```
>   AudioQueueNewInput(
>                        &audioDescription,
>                        recordingCallback, self,
>                        CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 0,
>                        &mInputQueue
>                        );
> ```

But i want to run this in a seperate RunLoop..How to create custom CFRunLoop ?
Please help me..Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new run loop by creating a new thread, they are thread bound and you shouldn't mess with it. I don't see a reason why you want to have a new run loop anyway, could you please tell us what you want to achieve?